# What's the best way to call another resolver in Apollo Server?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

Say you wanted to call the `createdAt` resolver from the `updatedAt` resolver. For example this doesn't work:

```js
{
  Review: {
    createdAt: review => review._id.getTimestamp(),
    updatedAt: review => review.updatedAt || this.createdAt(review)
  },
}
```

I realize I could make a `reviewCreatedAt()` function that is called from both, but I'm looking for a way to call the `createdAt` resolver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard way to call another resolver. Using `this` won't work even if you don't use an arrow function because the context is lost when the resolver is called by the underlying code. You can do something like this:

```
const resolvers = {
  Review: {
    createdAt: review => review._id.getTimestamp(),
    updatedAt: review => review.updatedAt || resolvers.Review.createdAt(review)
  },
}
```

If you're using a data model, though, you may find it easier to just lift this logic into the data model (using a calculated or virtual field).